# Proof of $\operatorname{Corr}\left(X, Y\middle|Z\right) = \operatorname{Corr}(X-\hat X, Y-\hat Y)$

Tags: correlation

The text I'm reading claims that for multivariate $X$, $Y$, and $Z$, and $\hat X$ and $\hat Y$ are the regression of $X$ and $Y$ on $Z$ we have that

> $$\operatorname{Corr}\left(X, Y\middle|Z\right) = \operatorname{Corr}(X-\hat X, Y-\hat Y)$$

However, there was no derivation of this claim. What steps are required to show this identity, and why is the assumption of normal variables required?

Comment: Do you mean $Corr(X|Z, Y|Z)$, or just $Corr(X, Y|Z)$? In the first, you regress Z out of both X and Y; this is the partial correlation between X and Y conditional on Z. In the second, you regress Z out of only Y; this is a semipartial correlation with Y conditional on Z.

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate notation. I intended $\operatorname{Corr}\left((X,Y)\middle|Z\right)$, which I believe corresponds to $\operatorname{Corr}\left(X|Z,Y|Z\right)$?

Comment: $\operatorname{Corr}(X,Y|Z)$ is perfectly fine notation, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_covariance whereas $\operatorname{Corr}(X|Z,Y|Z)$ is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitional and comes from the fact that $$X_i = Z_i\beta_x + \epsilon_{xi}$$, $$\hat{X}_i = Z_i\beta_x$$ and $$X_i|Z_i = \epsilon_{xi} = X_i - Z_i\beta_x = X_i - \hat{X}_i$$ (and the same for $Y$). These all come from the definition of regression. Then you can simply substitute: $$Corr(X,Y|Z) = Corr(X|Z, Y|Z) = Corr(X - \hat{X}, Y - \hat{Y})$$.

Comment: So there is no need to assume the variables to be normal?

Comment: Perhaps I'm wrong (I think I received a downvote for this one), but I don't think you need that assumption.

Comment: This doesn't look right to me.  Your equation $\hat{X}_i = Z_i \beta_x$ uses the true coefficient $\beta_x$ rather than the corresponding OLS estimator.  You seem to be looking at the true error terms rather than residuals.

Comment: That's true, and probably an oversimplification, but I believe this identity works on both the error term and the residuals, i.e., in both the population (using the true $\beta_x$) and the sample (using the estimated $\hat{\beta}_x$). The quantity $X|Z$ doesn't imply that we're in sample mode, and nothing about the structure of the proof necessitates examining either the sample or population.

Comment: -1 This equality is certainly not necessarily true unless we are talking about a multivariate normal distribution.

Comment: @JarleTufto why does the distribution matter? If $\hat{X}$ refers to the true mean (instead of estimated mean) then don't we have $$X-\hat{X} - mean{(X-\hat{X})} = X \vert Z - mean{(X \vert Z)}$$?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings I'm not sure I understand your comment.  I believe $\hat X$ in the OP refers to the regression of $X$ on $Z$, or more precicely, the linear minimum mean square error predictor of $X$ based on $Z$.  So $\hat X$ is a function of $Z$.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings In general $\operatorname{Corr}(X,Y|Z)$ depends on the value $Z$ we condition on.  So the left hand side don't necessarily equal the right hand side (which is just some constant) except in the multvariate normal case.

Answer (score 1):

For a multivariate normal random vector partitioned as $\mathbf{x}=\left[\begin{matrix}\mathbf{x}_1 \\ \mathbf{x}_2\end{matrix}\right]$, the conditional distribution of $\mathbf{x}_1$ conditional on on $\mathbf{x}_2$ is also multivariate normal with [mean vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions) equal to the general expression for the best [linear minimum mean square error predictor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_mean_square_error#Linear_MMSE_estimator) $\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1$ of $\mathbf{x}_1$ based on $\mathbf{x}_2$ (applying to any multivariate distribution) and, importantly, a variance-covariance matrix that does not depend on $\mathbf{x}_2$.

In the multivariate normal case we can thus write
$$
\mathbf{x}_1=\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1 + \mathbf{e}_1,
$$ 
where $\mathbf{e}_1$ is independent of $\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1$ and multivariate normal with zero mean and variance-covariance matrix equal to the the above conditional variance-covariance matrix.

Hence,
$$
\operatorname{Var}(\mathbf{x}_1-\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1) = \operatorname{Var}\mathbf{e}_1=\operatorname{Var}(\mathbf{x}_1|\mathbf{x}_2),
$$
that is, all variances, covariances and correlations of deviations from $\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1$ equals the corresponding conditional quantities.

This equality does not hold in general, however, as we can easily construct a multivariate distribution for which the conditional variance-covariance matrix of $\mathbf{x}_1$ depends on $\mathbf{x}_2$.

Comment: I believe I am a bit stuck in definitions. I get that the $x_2$ dependency of $Var(x_1|x_2)$ but would not equally the distribution of the heterogeneous error-term $Var(x_1-\hat{x}_1)$ change depending on $x_2$? Or is this term related to the residuals? Or is the term not considered to be conditional or evaluated over all $x_2$? It is a bit confusing that $\hat{x}_1$ is ambiguous.

Comment: $\hat x_1=\mu_1 + \Sigma_{12}\Sigma_{22}^{-1}(x_2-\mu_2)$ is just another random variable defined on the same sample space as $x_1$ so $\operatorname{Var}(x_1-\hat x_1)$ is just some constant whereas $\operatorname{Var}(x_1|x_2)$ may depend on $x_2$.